# System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Many times in day, application produces, randomly this exactly exception. This will be happen sometimes every 1-2 hours or can be crash-free for 7-8. The application is on production and is developed with Xamarin.Forms.

> JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) System.ArgumentException:
>   Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance
>
> JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod
>   (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue*
>   parms) AppCompatButton.set_SupportBackgroundTintList
>   (Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList value)
>   ButtonRenderer.UpdateBackgroundColor ()
>   VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementPropertyChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementPropertyChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating any `Button` instances that you do not have a hard-reference to?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, any button in listview is created dynamically, and any button can change background color by someone else in the same application.

Comment: `Handle must be valid` and `UpdateBackgroundColor...` Then I would assume an instance is being GC'd and you are trying to reference it somewhere and change its color....

Comment: Can I somehow handle the GC or generally handle this problem?

Comment: You could try to put your buttons into a list and put the list into `Application.Current.Properties`.